# ElasticSearch Sorting results based on multiple fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have an index which stores information about products. Each product has a few relevant fields for the search - title, description and length, width, height.
Basically the idea is the users can input something like 'PC Carton Box 55 60 75' meaning they want to browse for PC Carton boxes, that have the specified dimensions.
The order of the items returned must be the following:

1. Products that have hits in title (PC Carton Box) and products that have ideally all the same dimensions
2. Products with hits in title and products that have some/similar LWH params
3. Products found only by title hits
4. Products found only by dimension hits

The search query itself is the following:

```
$formatted_args['query'] = [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'should' => [
                                'multi_match' => [
                                    'query' => 'PC Carton Box',
                                    'fields' => ['post_title'],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'should' => [
                                ['match' => ['length' => ['query' => 48]]],
                                ['match' => ['width' => ['query' => 40]]],
                                ['match' => ['height' => ['query' => 60]]],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

I tried setting up the weight of title/dimensions so they have proper results but one just overrides the other.

The document contains entries as follows:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "PC Carton Box",
    "description": "Suitable for most PCs",
    "price": "549",
    "discountPercentage": "12.96",
    "rating": "4.69",
    "stock": "94",
    "brand": "Boxys",
    "length": "55",
    "width": "60"
    "height": "75"
  },
```

Comment: At least, share your sample document

Comment: @D.T added sample entry in the description.

Comment: could you also shared the way you set up `weight` and share the unexpected result?